# Catch all exception in C#

Tags: c#, exception

How can I handle exceptions that will close my program like error in disposing...

```
[SecurityPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, Flags = SecurityPermissionFlag.ControlAppDomain)]
        static void Main()
        {

            AppDomain currentDomain = AppDomain.CurrentDomain;
            currentDomain.UnhandledException += new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(MyHandler);

            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Form1());

            try
            {
                throw new Exception("1");
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Catch clause caught : {0} \n", e.Message);
            }

            throw new Exception("2");
        }

        static void MyHandler(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs args)
        {
            Exception e = (Exception)args.ExceptionObject;
            MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
        }
    }
```

In my code, I cant handle some exceptions and my program will crashed. for example when It get some error in disposing and something like this...

any idea for fixing that? I want that my program dont stop not at all.

Comment: Just remember, you can't catch **ALL** exceptions.

Comment: @Habib http://blog.codinghorror.com/content/images/uploads/2012/07/6a0120a85dcdae970b0176169669bd970c-800wi.jpg

Comment: @asawyer, ahh that [Pokémon Exception Handling](http://blog.codinghorror.com/new-programming-jargon/)